# NSSlider multiple undo registrations

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an NSSlider set to continuous mode. Hence, as the user moves the slider, my action method gets called multiple times. We need to do undo registration only for the last value of slider and we need not track so many intermediate values. I understand that I can turn undo registration off using `disableUndoRegistration` on undo manager and turn it back on using `enableUndoRegistration` but where do I call these so that we don't make multiple undo registrations?

```
- (IBAction) changeSpacing:(id) sender {
    self.someValue = [sender floatValue];    
    //do undo registration, I would prefer to do this only for the last
    //value of the slider
    [[[myDocument undoManager] prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setSomeValue:oldValue]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSEvent` may help you.

```
- (IBAction) changeSpacing:(id) sender {
    self.someValue = [sender floatValue];    

    NSEvent *event = [NSApplication sharedApplication].currentEvent;
    if (event.type == NSLeftMouseUp) {
        // end dragging
        [[[myDocument undoManager] prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setSomeValue:oldValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! Now the question is if everyone implements undo for an NSSlider operation like this or there is a better way?

Comment: another approach is creating `NSSlider` subclass. then override `mouseDown:` method and notify the mouse-up just after calling super's `mouseDown:`. `NSSlider` never calls `mouseUp:`, so we need workaround like that. but this way is not elegant, i think.